# Time for a riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Here's a riddle. It's my first on here so hopefully it's not too easy. Since you can't really solve a riddle you came up with, it's difficult to judge how hard they are.

> My stem's planted firmly where I am allotted.
>   My tail is wavy and my face is quite blotted.
>   I relay much emotion though flatly I'm spotted,
>   And I grow half my size whenever I'm dotted.
>   I can speak any language, yet utter no words.
>   I'm no seed, yet I am well known among birds.
>
> But I do have a speech impediment:
>   I can say cage but not page, aged but not wage.
>   I can say deaf but not red, bed but not sled.
>
> I live on a highway that's structurally sound,
>   Where you might see my friends accidentally bound.
>   It has many lanes, and also long lines.
>   There are lots of sharp turns, but plenty of signs.
>
> I am played but not won, made but not spun.
>   The key is to measure before you've begun.
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are:

> **Music**

```
My stem's planted firmly where I am allotted.
My tail is wavy and my face is quite blotted.
I relay much emotion though flatly I'm spotted,
And I grow half my size whenever I'm dotted.
```

> This describes an eighth note - a stem, a wavy tail, a filled-in face;
>  the half-again growth when dotted is what gave it away to me.

```
I can speak any language, yet utter no words.
I'm no seed, yet I am well known among birds.
```

> Music has no words of its own, but can be used to express feelings to anyone of any language.  And, of course, song-birds sing musically.

```
But I do have a speech impediment:
I can say cage but not page, aged but not wage.
I can say deaf but not red, bed but not sled.
```

> The notes of music only run A-G, so the indicated words can either be spelled with those letters (cage, aged, deaf, bed) or not (the rest).

```
I live on a highway that's structurally sound,
Where you might see my friends accidentally bound.
It has many lanes, and also long lines.
```

> These lines describe the staves of musical notation

```
There are lots of sharp turns, but plenty of signs.
```

> Sharp notes, rests, and so on are other items of musical notation.

```
I am played but not won, made but not spun.
The key is to measure before you've begun.
```

> Music is played and made, but not won or spun.
>  "Key" and "measure" are additional musical terms for things usually signalled at the start of a piece (well, of a staff line anyway) in the sharps or flats and with the time signature.

Comment: Even without seeing explanation, I can see how this answer fits all the given clues. Well done, man!

Comment: Nice answer! I briefly thought of music when I read the "I can speak any language" line, but the thought wasn't bright enough to shine through the other lines.

Comment: Right you are! I hoped it would last a bit longer than this, but hey. I'm good at poetry, not making puzzles, lol.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked out all the clues, but I suspect you're

> a piece of paper with writing on it.

*My stem's planted firmly where I am allotted.*

> The "stem" being a pen or pencil used to write with?

*My tail is wavy and my face is quite blotted.*

> Not sure what the "tail" is (perhaps writing tailing off in a curve?), but the "face", the sheet of paper, would be blotted with ink after having been written on.

*I relay much emotion though flatly I'm spotted,*

> Written words can relay much emotion, even though they're just dots of ink on a flat surface.

*And I grow half my size whenever I'm dotted.*

> Not quite sure about this - something to do with dotting the i's and crossing the t's maybe?

*I can speak any language, yet utter no words.*

> Definitely.

*I'm no seed, yet I am well known among birds.*

> Birds using paper to line their nests?

*But I do have a speech impediment:*
*I can say cage but not page, aged but not wage.*
*I can say deaf but not red, bed but not sled.*

> I'm not really sure about this verse. Presumably it's something to do with how those words are written down.

*I live on a highway that's structurally sound,*

> A pad or ream of paper.

*Where you might see my friends accidentally bound.*

> A book consists of sheets of paper "bound" together.

*It has many lanes, and also long lines.*

> Lined or ruled paper with margins.

*There are lots of sharp turns, but plenty of signs.*

> Written signs on the paper, and right angles at the corners?

*I am played but not won, made but not spun.*
*The key is to measure before you've begun.*

> I'm not quite sure about this verse either.

Comment: Good guess - you were halfway there at least.